# Vuejs parameters in props

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, chart.js, vue-component

Is it possible to pass props as funcitions on VueJs?

```
<template>
    <line-chart 
    class="card-content" 
    :chartData="lineData2('Temp')" 
    :options="options" 
    :width="800">
    </line-chart>
</template>
```

The `chartData` prop can be used as a method? Is there any way to pass a method on a prop?

Cheers,

Comment: Have you tried this? I think it should work.

Answer (score 4):

It depends on what you are trying to do. If you want to pass an actual function and not the result of a function, you can do:

```
<line-chart class="card-content" :chartData="() => lineData2('Temp')" :options="options" :width="800"></line-chart>
```

Which will pass the `lineData2` function itself, however, it will still be executed in the parent scope and not in the component scope, so it won't have any access to the components `this` context.

Here's a JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rz8c1v4L/

If you just want to pass the result of the function then what you are doing is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. As long as your function returns a value. Everything should work.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can! You can achieve that by mentioning the **type** of your prop, as it is clearly written in Vue's documentation. For e.g.

```
Vue.component('example', {
  props: {
    propA: {
      type: function
    }
  }
})
```

Also checkout this [link](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html)